# Unable to update Dashboard with data from sql Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sqflite

My Flutter app has a Dashboard with a chart as the first screen. The data for the chart comes from local sql database. I have a Future async call to get the data through the database provider.

My current issue is that on a real device, the init() call does not fetch the data and so the chart is not populated. However, when I navigate to another screen and get back to the dashboard, the data is populated.

Appreciate any help in letting me know what could be the issue.

Below is my code for the initState calling the function _getExpTotal();

```
class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _seriesLineData = List<charts.Series<Sales, int>>();
    _getExpTotal();
  }
```

And below is the Future async function _getExpTotal()

```
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _getExpTotal() async {
    final result = await databaseProvider.getCatExpTotal();
    expTotal = result;
    count = result.length;
    print(count);
    _getChartData();
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> _getChartData() async {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      String mon = (expTotal[i]['mon-Year']);
      int exp = (expTotal[i]['TranAmount']);
      mon = mon.substring(0, 2);
      print(int.parse(mon));
      linesalesdata.add(Sales(int.parse(mon), exp));
    }
    _generateData();
  }
```

and finally _generateData() to update the chart:

```
  _generateData() {
    _seriesLineData.add(charts.Series(
      colorFn: (__, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor((Colors.blueGrey)),
      id: 'Expense by Month',
      data: linesalesdata,
      domainFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.yearval,
      measureFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.salesval,
      labelAccessorFn: (Sales row, _) => '${row.yearval}',
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are calling your _getExpTotal(); function from initState() which returns a list of Map<String,dynamic> but you are not really using that returned data. Also, you can not use await in initState() so I would say that your chose a wrong place to call your _getExpTotal(); function. Here's something that should help you out.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _seriesLineData = List<charts.Series<Sales, int>>();
    _renderGraph();
    //Stop calling _getExpTotal() here.
  }
```

Create a function "renderGraph()"

```
void _renderGraph() async {
  List<Map<String,dynamic>> returnedData = await _getExpTotal();
  //Use returned data here however you want.
  setState((){
    
  });
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above solution though I did not see much difference between using _getExpTotal directly in init() vs using _renderGraph(). As both these are async/await functions. Correct me if I am wrong. 
My problem is that both the solutions work when I connect my device to Android Studio, but when I disconnect and run it independently, init() is not called. 
Any further suggestions?

Comment: init() is always called once when your UI renders for the first time, no matter what. init() is called only once that's why it is called init(). Your code shows that you are not consuming the List of maps returned from your function. Also, you are not calling setState(() {}) after fetching the data. Calling setState(() {}) is important to render the new state of your UI.